# Spring MVC is confusing get and post methods with the same request mapping

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a login controller that I've mapped the "/login" path to two different methods.  One will be called for get and the other for post.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Model model){
    LoginDto loginDto = new LoginDto();
    model.addAttribute("loginDto", loginDto);
    return "home/login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doLogin(@Valid LoginDto loginDto, BindingResult bindingResult){
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        return "home/login";
    }
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

I have the thymeleaf form

```
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${loginDto}">
    <div class="form-group-row">
        <label> Email </label>
        <input type = "text" th:field = "*{email}"/>
        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors = "*{email}"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label> Password </label>
        <input type = "text" th:field = "*{password}"/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When enter data and click submit the method with the GET request is called.  I know this from inserting breakpoints in both methods.  Also the url now has a ?errors at the end of it.  I've also changed the url mapping to the second method to "doLogin" like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dologin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doLogin(@Valid LoginDto loginDto, BindingResult bindingResult){
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        return "home/login";
    }
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

and changed the form to this

```
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/dologin}" th:object="${loginDto}">
    <div class="form-group-row">
        <label> Email </label>
        <input type = "text" th:field = "*{email}"/>
        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors = "*{email}"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label> Password </label>
        <input type = "text" th:field = "*{password}"/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and it works.  I can enter data and hit the submit button and I'm in the doLogin method.  However, I would like to keep this mapping of GET and POST to the same url to do different things based on the request method.

Further more, when I created the form at first, I forgot to specify a method="post" and while testing it submitted get requests to "/login" from this form.  Perhaps that wired something up that needs to be unwired.

Is this a bug?  I can map the same url with different request methods to other controller methods but this one doesn't seem to want to work.  Any Ideas?

Comment: I am not sure but trying with "th:method' in form tag would work.

Comment: Just tried "th:method" in the form tag and it has the same behaviour.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out.  The reason the method that is mapped to the POST request is because I'm using spring security and it's not completely set up.  The login page for spring security was mapped to /login as well and the appended

```
localhost/login?error
```

to the url string is something spring security appends when there is an error with the login process.  I have not set up authentication with spring security yet so it believes there's an error.  I will continue on setting up spring security but this is the reason my POST request was not mapped to the doLogin method.